# A particular multiple of 99

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

What is the smallest multiple of 99 which begins with 97, ends with 97 and the sum of its digits is equal to 99 ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know the divisibility test for $11$?  Why would I ask?  What is the sum of the digits excluding the $97$s?  How many digits does that take?

Comment: This was more fun than I expected.  We want the minimum number of digits, and within numbers with the same number of digits to have the leading ones as small as possible.  It takes at least 11 9s to add to 99, and we need a couple 7s, so there must be at least 12 digits.  This would give $97a,b99,999,997$ as a candidate.  The digit sum says $a+b=13$ but divisibility by $11$ says $a=b$, so we can't have $12$ digits.  For $13$ digits we have $9,7ab,999,999,997$.  To get the digit sum we need $a+b=4$ and to get divisibility by $11$ we need $a-b=2$, so $a=3, b=1$ and we have $9,731,999,999,997$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Note that sum of digits being $99$ means it is already divisible by $9$.

Also, being divisible by $11$ means that the sum of the odd digits minus the sum of the even digits must be equal to a multiple of $11$. So if the sum of these two values is $99$, that means that the sum of every other digit must be a multiple of $11$.

So you want the smallest number that starts with $97$, ends with $97$, has digit sum $99$ and the odd digits add up to a multiple of $11$.